# Radgrid column batch editing enable /disable based on condition

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a `RadGrid` with `EditMode` set to `Batch`. I want to disable column editing on certain conditions like for condition "A" I need editing enabled and for condition "B" I need to disable editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used java-script:

In RadGrid you just add code:

```
<ClientSettings ...
     <ClientEvents  OnRowClick="OnRowClick" />
...>
```

In JavaScript:

```js
function OnRowClick(sender, eventArgs) {
    var RowID = eventArgs.get_id(); //get Row
    var masterTable = $find("<%=rdGrid.ClientID%>").get_masterTableView(); //get Grid
    var ControlX = masterTable.get_dataItems()[RowID].findElement('ControlX').id; //get Control ID
    //check conditions then disable or enable...
    $(ControlX).prop('disabled', false); //Get Control and Disable the editing
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this , and it worked.

```
       <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation ="true">
       <ClientEvents OnBatchEditOpening="batchEditOpening" OnBatchEditOpened="batchEditOpened" OnBatchEditClosed="OnBatchEditClosed" OnKeyPress ="KeyPress" />
    </ClientSettings>

function batchEditOpening(sender, args) {
    var rulesValue = document.getElementById("cphContent_LoginAuditControl_RolesHiddenField").value;
    if (args.get_columnUniqueName() == "Reason" || args.get_columnUniqueName() == "Comment") {
        if (rulesValue == 'false') {
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
```